# Change background image on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I currently have some php that changes the background image of a div everytime the page is refreshed.

In the head of my HTML I have this

```
<?php 
$bg = rand(1, 6); 
$bgchange = $bg.".jpg"; 
?>
```

and then this

```
<style type="text/css">
.cover {
  background-image: url('../img/backgrounds/<?php echo $bgchange; ?>');
}
</style>
```

As you can see this is a very simple bit of php it does do the job but I am having problems when the site is first loaded on a computer or if the internet is slow where the image fails to load.

Any javascript guys that can recommend a solution to this I would greatly appreciate, I'm also thinking javascript will be better as the image can 'fade' in etc. I am referencing jquery-1.10.2 in my project.

P.S. Solution does not have to be javascript if anyone knows how to improve my php code or can offer a reason why the code fails sometimes, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

First create an array of images:

```
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg'];
```

Then, set a random image as the background image:

```
 $('body').css({'background-image': 'url(images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *      images.length)] + ')'});
```

That should work no problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can do (and should) do this action in js.

on the document load function you can do this.
   //document load function

```
$(function(){

    var bgImage = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6))+ ".jpg;"
    $('.cover').css('background-image',"../img/backgrounds/"+bgImage);
});
```

and this way you can keep using the folders you are using and not change anything.

Comment: I removed my current .php code and tried including this code in-between two script tags in the head of my HTML, did not work for some reason, I got an unexpected token error in the console.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: copy paste this two lines of code two your head tag and you will be good to go.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>